# Geometric Brownian Motion - Normal distribution

Tags: statistics

I have the following formula:

[Geometric Brownian Model Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHLum.png)

Does anyone know if the portion highlighted in yellow, corresponds to a normal distribution with mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1? Or is it a uniform distribution between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the former, i.e. a normal random variable with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.

(If you search up a proof of the solution to the geometric brownian motion stochastic differential equation, you will see a "Wiener process"/brownian motion term appearing, which is where the normal distribution comes from.)